# R: Write a function to produce a number with decimal points

Tags: r, decimal-point

I wanted to generate a number with a certain decimal point when a number indicating the decimal point is given. So, simply speaking, if 1 is given, generate .1. If 2 is given, generate .01, and so on.

```
1 => .1
2 => .01
3 => .001
4 => .0001 and so on.
```

Do you guys have any idea on that?

Thanks.

Comment: `foo = function(x) 10^-x`. Testing: `foo(1:3) [1] 0.100 0.010 0.001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
#p is input integer here 
func1 <- function(p){

return (10^(-p))

}
```